# fix corrupted shelve cache

Tags: python, database, shelve

A shelve that I've created isn't allowing me to access the keys without the following failure.

`x = shelve.open('my_shelve.pkl')
x.keys()`

`bsddb.db.DBPageNotFoundError: (-30986, 'BDB0075 DB_PAGE_NOTFOUND: Requested page not found')`

However, I am able to check if the Shelf contains a key like so:

`'some-key' in x`,

and additionally, the Shelf will return the correct data with

`x['some-key']`

I don't have the list of keys elsewhere, so I'd like to somehow retrieve the keys so I can retrieve the data, or otherwise fix the issue with the database.

I'm using Python 2.7.6

Comment: What's the exact error message with line numbers? You can edit the library code if you know which line the error originates on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the database file is damaged (e.g, maybe by failing to call `close` on it in the past), you probably can't recover *all* of its contents (the file format just doesn't have enough redundancy to support that).

However, you could perhaps recover a *part* of it as follows:

```
recov = {}
try:
    for k in x:
        recov[k] = x[k]
except Exception:
    pass
```

It's impossible to predict how many keys (and associated values) you'll be able to recover this way, but at least by not asking for *all* keys (as I imagine you're doing with `x.keys()` -- you don't tell us which Python version you're using, but I guess it's 2.something) you might be able to recover *some* of them...

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.6, but I was unable to recover any contents with this (it fails before even entering the loop body)

Comment: Then try recovering some data with Python 3.4, which uses slightly different logic. If that also fails completely, then that suggests the damage to your file is too vast to let you recover anything much.